# Br- and I- ions give layer test, but Cl- ion doesn't. Why?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, redox

In a paragraph about "non-metal displacement", my book talks about chlorine displacing bromide and iodide ions in an aqueous solution. This results in the evolution of bromine/iodine gas depending upon the reaction. When the evolved gas is dissolved in Carbon tetrachloride, the resulting colour change is used to determine the presence of Bromide and Chloride ions in the laboratory. This test is named as 'Layer test' in my textbook.

My question is, if chlorine gas is dissolved in Carbon tetrachloride will it induce a colour change? If not, why?

One of the questions I found in an NCERT book. Interestingly I could not find the answer anywhere on the internet. Hence, stack exchange.

Comment: Welcome to ChemSE.  Please substantiate your question by addition of futher information providing (chemical) context + at least the start of your argumentation to solve the question.  Layer of what?  Since NCERT is an organisation, would it be a question about organic chemistry or inorganic chemistry or something else?

Comment: @Buttonwood The organization NCERT writes textbooks for Indian schools which are colloquially called NCERT books, and the chemistry textbook contains organic, physical and inorganic chemistry together. And BTW I haven't come across this "Layer test" ever in it, but again I never read the book seriously.

Comment: @Soham can you type out how the "Layer test" described in the book? Some chemical context is mandatory. I can't find anything by that name anywhere.

Comment: This (Layer test) is an ancient chemical method. It's as outdated as the theory that everything is made of five elements. If you want to study real chemistry don't read NCERT. It's a really difficult read and hasn't been reeditioned in decades.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The so called layer test is a qualitative analysis of bromide and iodide salts (old school chemistry). The salts are oxidized in water and then chloroform or carbon tetrachloride is added. This forms a layer. Since the partition coefficient of iodine or bromine is much higher for the organic solvent, a colored layer is formed sitting in the bottom of the test tube (hence the name layer test). Bromine shows an orange color and iodine shows a beautiful violet color. Chlorine is almost colorless, it is a gas, it will not be visible in these chlorinated solvents. And above all, very few oxidizing agents can form chlorine with chloride.

Answer (score 4):

Organic Layer test is a test involving redox reactions among halides. This test is used to detect in the presence of bromide ions and iodide ions in a solution (*e.g.*, Lassaigne’s test solution).  Layer test is carried out by adding organic solvent such as carbon disulphide or chloroform in the presence of nitric acid and chlorine water to the given solution. For example, Lassaigne’s extract is acidified with dilute nitric acid and chlorine water is added to it. When organic solvent is added to this aqueous solution and shaken the mixture vigorously but carefully, the liberated bromine or iodine liberated by redox reaction of bromide or iodide ions with chlorine) would be traveled to organic layer to give distinguished color. In case bromine is present, it will give an orange layer while it will give a violet layer in case of presence of Iodine. Relevant redox reactions are given below:

$$\ce{Br- + Cl2 -> Br2 + Cl-}$$
$$\ce{I- + Cl2 -> I2 + Cl-}$$

The key is bromine and iodine are much soluble in organic solvents than in water. Since we are using chlorine as a oxidant, chloride ions are negated here.